# Mensaje "Bad Request" al abrir shorturl generada con quickchart.io/create

Tags: php, chart.js

He generado un grafico generado con https://www.chartjs.org/, del cual quiero obtener una imagen jpg. Para ello utilizo https://quickchart.io/.

```
https://quickchart.io/chart?c={type:'bar',data:{labels:[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],datasets:[{label:'Users',data:[120,60,50,180,120]}]}}
```

Cuando se generan muchos datos para obtener el grafico, me devuelve error indicando "que la linea es demasiado larga". Por ello estoy intentando generar una url corta con https://quickchart.io/chart/create.

```
  $chart = json_encode("{'chart': {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [-31, -70, -30, -33, -9, 14, -41],
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [73, 41, 29, 61, -65, 59, 38],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Bar Chart',
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
        color: '#666',
        font: {
          weight: 'normal',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}}");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://quickchart.io/chart/create');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $chart); 
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);   
} else {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($exec);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

La respuesta me genera la siguiente salida:

```
{"success":true,"url":"https://quickchart.io/chart/render/zf-4bd56892-2217-433c-9e1a-99d91af0a538"}
```

... pero la url generada, siempre me devuelve la mismo mensaje de `Bad Request` y no se donde esta el problema.

¿alguna solucion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el json_encode() formatea tu cadena a JSON pero sigue devolviendo un formato String (agregando \r\n a la salida) y no como un objeto JSON. Una forma rápida de solucionar este problema es formatear correctamente la cadena JSON y enviarla directamente con el CURL sin pasar por el json_encode().

Otra forma de resolverlo es forzando la data a objetos y luego convertirlo a json con el json_encode() y se siente mas natural la construcción

Te dejo el ejemplo

```
$obj = (object) [
    'chart' => (object)[
        'type' => 'bar',
        'data' => (object)[
            'labels' => array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"),
            'datasets' => array(
                (object)[
                    'label'=> 'Dataset 1',
                    'backgroundColor' => "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
                    'borderColor' => "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                    'borderWidth' => 1,
                    'data' => array(-31, -70, -30, -33, -9, 14, -41)
                ],
                (object)[
                    'label'=> 'Dataset 2',
                    'backgroundColor' => "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)",
                    'borderColor' => "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    'borderWidth' => 1,
                    'data' => array(73, 41, 29, 61, -65, 59, 38)
                ],
            )
        ],
        'options' => (object)[
            'title' => (object)[
                'display' => true,
                'text'=> "Bar Chart"
            ],
            'title' => (object)[
                'datalabels' =>(object)[
                    'anchor'=> "center",
                    'align'=> "center",
                    'color'=> "#666",
                    'font'=> (object)['weight' => 'normal']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$chart = json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: Hola. He probado con una cadena más sencilla ("{'chart': {'type': 'bar', 'data': {'labels': ['Hello', 'World'],'datasets': [{'label': 'Foo', 'data': [1, 2]}]}}}") ... pero me sigue devolviendo la misma respuesta erronea ... :-(

Comment: El detalle está en el formato. Prueba `$chart ='{"chart":{"type":"bar","data":{"labels":["Hello","World"],"datasets":[{"label":"Foo","data":[1,2]}]}}}'`

Comment: Con objetos funciona PERFECTAMENTE !!!!! .... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Abriendo directamente el enlace que proporcionaste (https://quickchart.io/chart/create), el resultado es:

```
success: false
error: "Expecting POST with Content-Type application/json"
```

Resumen: Debes enviar todas las peticiones por método POST; si no especificas este método, la petición se hará por GET, quedando esa URL demasiado larga, por la cantidad de datos (primer mensaje de error).

Si envías menos datos (url más corta), recibirás el segundo error (Bad request), por hacer la petición por método GET.

Solución: Antes de enviar la petición, asegúrate de que se usará el método adecuado:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://quickchart.io/chart/create');

// Enviar petición por POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $chart);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
```

Referencia de opciones de cURL: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Hola. He especificado el método POST (CURLOPT_POST = true) ... pero sigue respondiendo "Bad Request" ...

Comment: @osbragon, ahora revisa que el JSON está bien formado, copiando y pegando en https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  ... Creo que la mejor opción sería crear un arreglo asociativo y convertirlo con `json_encode()` para asegurar que no hay errores.

Comment: He revisado el formato JSON con el validador, y me indica que es correcto. He probado con numero de datos mucho menor (para evitar errores), y tambien me dice lo mismo. :-(

Comment: @osbragon,  comienza reduciendo las opciones, como en el ejemplo de la [página principal](https://quickchart.io/). Ya que veas que funciona, ve agregando las demás, para ubicar cuál es la causa del error.